# What is a non-complete simple geodesic on closed hyperbolic surface?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-topology

I saw the words "complete simple geodesic" in many places. But I can't not figure out an example of simple geodesic which is not complete on closed hyperbolic surface. I think a gedesic ray can be non-complete but in case of gedesic, I don't know. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha:\mathbb{R} \to S$ be a complete closed geodesic that its image in $S$ intersects itself transversely in a single point, e.g. a geodesic representative (with respect to a chosen hyperbolic structure) of the homotopy class of a "figure eight" encircling the two holes of a closed genus two surface as you might draw this surface in the usual way in 3-space.  Choose a maximal interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha:I \to S$ is one-to-one.  Then $\alpha$ is a simple geodesic, but it cannot be extended and still remain a simple geodesic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose a maximal interval (for instance: $(0,1)\subset [0,1]$) as you said and the resulting geodesic is a simple geodesic but still a figure eight geometrically. So I guess that "non-completeness" here is only in the sense of "simple", not in the sense of metric, is it right?

Comment: Maybe you meant that we take a half of "figure eight" without the intersection point

Comment: Yes, it cannot be extended to a simple geodesic because it will intersect itself.  If you drop the condition that the geodesic be simple, then you can extend every geodesic on a closed surface with a hyperbolic surface.  This follows from the fact that the hyperbolic plane covers the surface and the hyperbolic plane is a complete metric space.  (You can apply the Hopf-Rinow Theorem.  Or you can see this directly: lift the geodesic (the parametrization, not the curve it traces) to $\mathbb{H}^2$; this extends to a bi-infinite geodesic  Then project the line back down via the covering.